# Delay the displaying of an element

Tags: jquery

I want to display a specific element after a given time and therefore try that on my localhost:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
//other things
$( "#recaller" ).delay(80000).css( "color", "red" );
}
```

And I do get #recaller colored red but instantly. Why is that?

Comment: Add a snippet code example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delay()` works for logic added to the `fx` animation queue, which `css()` is not. You could instead use a `setTimeout()` call to make this work:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  // other things
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#recaller').css('color', 'red');
  }, 80000);
});
```

Also note that it would be better to use `addClass()` to change the styling of the element instead of `css()`.